# Equal boxes in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-pic

I have written below latex script to make a table, but the size of boxes depends on the amount of text inside them and it makes everything messy. My questions are: 
1- Is there any way of making the sizes equal (for example by using the size of the largest box)? I appreciate your help.
2- Is there a way to shift the arrow which is on the bottom of the table just below the second column?

```
 \documentclass[
    12pt, % font size
    a4paper, % paper format
    oneside, % one-sided pages
    ]{report}

    \usepackage{tikz} % draw figures
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
    \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
    \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
    \usepackage{pgfplots} % discret signals
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}  
\def\etal{\emph{et al. }}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

    % math
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}

    \caption{Density and evolution of the virus}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (T) [matrix of nodes,column sep=4pt,row sep=4pt,nodes={draw,text width=3.3cm,align=center,rounded corners,minimum height=1.3cm,inner sep=1pt,font=\footnotesize,anchor=south}]
    {
     Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, tables and close to the entrance. It is necessary to be able to open the doors without touching them. & Clean the kitchen, all the bathrooms and area close to the entrance. Make sure you don not touch anything directly when you clean surfaces. &Investment plans, contracting with insurance companies  & Investment plans, contracting with insurance companies \\
    Every day, every month, every year. Even every hour. It should always be there regardless of time and date. Be ready to answer calls and open the door. & Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, tables and close to the entrance. tables and close to the entrance. & on desks, tables and close to the entrance. tables and close to the entrance.& Budget and cost allocation\\
     %Diagnosis and planning of an individual treatment & Appointment scheduling, workforce scheduling & Materials purchasing, determining order sizes & DRG billing, cash flow analysis\\
     %Triage, diagnosing emergencies and complications & Monitoring, emergency coordination & Rush ordering, inventory replenishing & Billing complications and changes\\                          
    };

    \node[yshift=-2mm,font=\bfseries] at (T.south west){$\xrightarrow{\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:}$};

    \node[yshift=-6mm,font=\bfseries] at (T.south west){Changing room};
    %\node[xshift=2mm,font=\large\bfseries,rotate=-90] at (T.east){$ \leftarrow $ \textbf{hierarchical decomposition} $ \rightarrow $};


    \matrix at (T.north west) [matrix of nodes,anchor=south west,yshift=-4mm,column sep=4pt,nodes={text width=3.3cm,align=center,minimum height=1.3cm,inner sep=1pt,font=\bfseries}]
    {
    Mondays  & Wednesday \par month & every \par week & Completely \par clean\\                           
    };


    \matrix at (T.north west) [matrix of nodes,anchor=north east,row sep=4pt,nodes={text width=2.3cm,align=right,minimum height=1.3cm,font=\bfseries}]
    {
    \\ \\  Time and space\\
    \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ 
    Only time\\
    %Offline \par Operational\\
    %Online \par Operational\\                          
    };
    \draw [densely dashed] (3.51,-2.5) -- (3.51,2.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

The red arrow shows the place that I want to put the arrow and its text.[image]

Edit:

I have used the solution in th first answer, but the whole table is now moved to the right hand side of the page! Could someone please help?

```
\documentclass[
    12pt, % font size
    a4paper, % paper format
    oneside, % one-sided pages
    ]{report}

    \usepackage{geometry}

    \usepackage{tikz} % draw figures
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
    \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
    \usepackage{pgfplots} % discret signals
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}  
\def\etal{\emph{et al. }}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

    % math
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}


      \begin{table}

    \caption{Wash all the surfaces.}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (T) [matrix of nodes,
                 column sep=4pt,
                 row sep=4pt,
                 nodes={draw,
                        text width=2.5cm,
                        align=center,
                        rounded corners,
                        minimum height=6cm,
                        inner sep=1pt,
                        font=\footnotesize,
                        anchor=south
                       }, 
                  row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum height=1cm, font=\bfseries}},
                  column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, text width=4.5cm, font=\bfseries}},
                  row 3/.style={nodes={minimum height=5.5cm}},
                 ]
    {& monday  & Intermediate \par week & Large \par wek & Completely \par month \\
     time \par phase 
        & Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, Wash all the surfaces and handles. & Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks. & Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks,  & Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra.  \\
    data \par phase 
        &Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, . &Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, Wash all the surfaces and handles. & Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, & Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome! One of the parameters you've added to the style of the nodes is `minimum height`, so in fact you already have one possible answer to the first question in your code. It's not automatic, but increasing that length would do it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you add a sketch showing where exactly you would like the arrow to be placed. Please also clarify: Do you want all boxed to share the same height or do you want all boxes in the same row to share the same height?

Comment: Please also clarify: Does "Time and space" belong to the first row of boxes and does "Only time" belong to the second row or is there a different desired alsignment of these texts width respect to the boxes?

Comment: The first question is answered in the first comment. For the second question, I've attached the picture. @leandriis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might serve as a point to start from. I have added `geometry` to get a wider text width and altered the width of the boxes to make the diagram fit into the text width.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[
    12pt, % font size
    a4paper, % paper format
    oneside, % one-sided pages
    ]{report}

    \usepackage{geometry}

    \usepackage{tikz} % draw figures
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
    \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
    \usepackage{pgfplots} % discret signals
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}  
\def\etal{\emph{et al. }}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

    % math
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}

    \caption{Density and evolution of the virus}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (T) [matrix of nodes,
                 column sep=4pt,
                 row sep=4pt,
                 nodes={draw,
                        text width=2.5cm,
                        align=center,
                        rounded corners,
                        minimum height=6cm,
                        inner sep=1pt,
                        font=\footnotesize,
                        anchor=south
                       }, 
                  row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum height=1cm, font=\bfseries}},
                  column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, text width=2.5cm, font=\bfseries}},
                  row 3/.style={nodes={minimum height=5.5cm}},
                  row 4/.style={nodes={minimum height=2cm}},
                  row 5/.style={nodes={minimum height=2cm}},
                 ]
    {& Mondays
        & Wednesday month 
            & every week 
                & completely clean \\
     Time and Space 
        & Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, tables and close to the entrance. It is necessary to be able to open the doors without touching them. 
            & Clean the kitchen, all the bathrooms and area close to the entrance. Make sure you don not touch anything directly when you clean surfaces. 
                &Investment plans, contracting with insurance companies  
                    & Investment plans, contracting with insurance companies \\
    Only time 
        &Every day, every month, every year. Even every hour. It should always be there regardless of time and date. Be ready to answer calls and open the door. 
            & Wash all the surfaces and handles. Put extra washing powder on desks, tables and close to the entrance. tables and close to the entrance. 
                & on desks, tables and close to the entrance. tables and close to the entrance.
                     & Budget and cost allocation\\
     Offline \par Operational & 
         Diagnosis and planning of an individual treatment 
             & Appointment scheduling, workforce scheduling 
                 & Materials purchasing, determining order sizes 
                     & DRG billing, cash flow analysis\\
     Online \par Operational 
         & Triage, diagnosing emergencies and complications 
             & Monitoring, emergency coordination 
                 & Rush ordering, inventory replenishing 
                     & Billing complications and changes\\                          
    };

     \draw[->]  ($(T-5-2.south)-(0,0.25)$) -- node [below, font=\bfseries] {Changing room} ($(T-5-3.south)-(0,0.25)$);

%    \draw [densely dashed] (3.51,-2.5) -- (3.51,2.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: When I remove your last two rows, the arrow goes to the table!

Comment: @Marco: Could you please clarify which rows you removed and what you mean with "goes to the table"? Do you refer to the last two rows of boxes?

Comment: That problem is solved, thanks. Is there any way of making the arrow thicker?

Comment: To change the arrow's line thickness, use `\draw[line width=1mm, ->]` or any other thickness of your choice.

Comment: I have removed the last two rows of your table, but now the table is moved towards the right-hand-side of the page! COuld you please the edit that I have made to the question?

Comment: You increased the width of the first column. (Add `column 1/.style={nodes={draw=red, text width=4.5cm, font=\bfseries}},` to see the width of the boxes). `text width=1.5cm` should be sufficient for the first column.

Comment: Thanks, but I need wider columns, because currently, they are very elongated

Comment: Which columns do you want to make wider? With `column 1/.style` you only make the first column wider. You can make the other columns (the ones with the boxes) wider if you use `text width=4.5cm,`  in `\matrix (T) [....]`. But be warned, your image will not fit onto the page if you make the boxed 4.5 cm wide. Use `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to see the available horizontal space. The maximum width you can use for the boxes in 3 cm, provided that your first column is only 1.5cm wide.